# How can I AFK all night on a Minecraft server with my laptop on sleep

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, hardware

I have recently joined a Minecraft server (it allows AFKing and has no timeout) and set up a bunch of AFK farms, and I want to AFK while I sleep. But my laptops fan (it’s clean, I checked) keeps me up at night. Is there a way to AFK all night with my PC on sleep mode (i tried but it said “timed out” when I turned it back on).

Comment: For clarification, you're basically trying to find out how your computer can run MineCraft without the noise of the fan keeping you from sleeping?

Comment: Yes, thats what i meant

Answer (score 3):

Sleep mode on a PC works by freezing all processor activity. All running programs are effectively stopped, but with their state still stored in memory so they can be resumed quickly. Unfortunately, this means you probably can't do what you are hoping to do. From the Minecraft server's point of view, your PC in sleep mode is indistinguishable from it being switched off.

If you are still determined to AFK while you sleep, your options are limited to trying to reduce or block the fan noise in some way: maybe put the computer in a different room at night, or install a quieter fan, or wear earplugs while you sleep, etc.

Comment: In many cases switching the computer to 'power save' power profile slows the processor down, and reduces the fan speed reducing its noise to inaudible levels. It may be a bit tricky to switch to this profile when the laptop is connected to the PSU, as the system detects external power and automatically switches to 'high performance' profile; switching to 'power save' with external power may require 3rd party tools. (on related note I regret this design choice; if I have 15 minutes to charge the battery before leaving, while making last checks on-line, I want most power going towards charging.)

Comment: From a suggested edit: "my question is is it really ok to like afk with the laptop having sleep mode? or if its not then what other ways for it that my device wont turn off bec im gon grind in pet sim x then my laptop turned off in the mid of night. -johanna eulysse"

Answer (score -2):

Your laptop will sleep only when all windows are closed.